# Rails 7.0.2.3 - link_to turbo_method: :delete issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-7

I am using Rails 7.0.2.3 and my website is active for two weeks now. Devise gem for authentication.

Recently (today) one of my colleagues noticed a problem. When clicking on sign_out he is receiving 404 not found. He is using Safari on Iphone, I tested the same on Chrome on Samsung, and on browsers on Desktop PC

This is my View

```
<%= link_to 'Одјави се', destroy_admin_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Одјави се?' }, class: 'nav-link' %>
```

These are the logs I am catching from heroku.

```
2022-04-16T16:23:02.349221+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admins/sign_out" host=www.mywebsite request_id=********* fwd="**.**.**" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=20331 protocol=https
2022-04-16T16:23:02.347534+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-16T16:23:02.347453 #4]  INFO -- : [*********] Started GET "/admins/sign_out" for **.**.**.** at 2022-04-16 16:23:02 +0000
2022-04-16T16:23:02.348459+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-04-16T16:23:02.348405 #4] FATAL -- : [*********]
2022-04-16T16:23:02.348460+00:00 app[web.1]: [*********] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admins/sign_out"):
2022-04-16T16:23:02.348460+00:00 app[web.1]: [*********]
```

I will point out that this was not a problem until today, probably yesterday if we haven't noticed. How can something like this affect from sudden? I am able to sign_out from Desktop using Brave browser, both on normal mode and on Incognito.

Any advise could be useful.
Thanks

Comment: For a logout button I would definately use `button_to 'Одјави се', destroy_admin_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Одјави се?' }, class: 'nav-link', method: :delete` instead of `link_to`. This creates an actual form and will work even if your JS fails completely due to an error or transport problems. Hardening the critical features like logging out is never a bad idea..

Comment: I found working solution with the button_to, but was not sure what I did wrong with link_to. Probably some js issues... Thank you Max!